# C# SMO Script user permissions using script option permissions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, smo

When using scripting option `Permissions` in SQL Server 2008 and above, the database creation script does not get scripted. Instead, an `ALTER DATABASE` statement is scripted.

I am using SQL Server 2008 and higher. Using C# SMO .Net assemblies v12.0.2000.8.

These are my script options:

```
ScriptingOptions so = new ScriptingOptions();

so.DriAll = true;
so.EnforceScriptingOptions = false;
so.IncludeDatabaseContext = true;
so.AllowSystemObjects = false;
so.IncludeHeaders = true;
so.IncludeIfNotExists = true;
so.Indexes = true;
so.NoCommandTerminator = false;
so.NoFileGroup = true;
// TODO: script user permissions
so.Permissions = true;
so.PrimaryObject = true;
so.SchemaQualify = true;
so.ScriptOwner = true;
so.ScriptSchema = true;
so.ScriptDrops = false;
so.Triggers = true;
//so.ExtendedProperties = true;
so.WithDependencies = false;
so.ScriptBatchTerminator = true;
so.TargetServerVersion = SqlServerVersion.Version105;
so.ContinueScriptingOnError = true;
```

I do not use a Transfer Object.

When I set `Permissions` to false, the `CREATE DATABASE` statement is generated. When I set `Permissions` to true, an `ALTER DATABASE` statement is scripted instead.

I want to be able to script the user permissions AND have the `CREATE DATABASE` statement included in the script instead of the `ALTER DATABASE` statement.

Comment: Just as a note: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **out of extended support** by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Comment: I said "I am using SQL Server 2008 and higher." We have 1 2008 R2 server and the rest are newer, but I still have to accommodate the older version for now.

Comment: Has no one seen this before? Maybe one of the other script options is causing this when Permissions is set to True? I could not find anything on it though.